# Moving files to Hadoop HDFS using SFTP

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sftp, cloudera

I've a VPC subnet which has multiple machines inside it.

On of the machine, I've some files stored. On another machine, I've hadoop HDFS service installed and running.

I need to move those files from first machine to HDFS file system using SFTP.

Do Hadoop has some API's that can achieve this goal ?

PS : I've installed Hadoop using Cloudera CDH4 distribution.

Answer (score 3):

This is a requirement which is much easier to implement on ftp/sftp server side than HDFS.

check out a ftp server works on top of HDFS [hdfs-over-ftp](https://github.com/iponweb/hdfs-over-ftp)

Answer (score 1):

A workflow written in Apache Oozie would do it. It comes with the Cloudera distribution. Other tools for orchestration could be Talend or PDI Kettle.